# How to prove A \/ False -> A in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq, theorem-proving

I am learning Coq and trying to prove "A \/ False -> A" but I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

I tried the following code:

```
Goal forall A False : Prop, A \/ False -> A.

Proof.

intros A False H.

destruct H as [HP | HQ].

apply HP.

exfalso.

apply HQ.
```

And expected to establish the premise for exfalso by applying the assumption HQ but it did not work and I got the following message: "Unable to unify "False" with "Logic.False"."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement you quantify over a proposition that you name `False`. There is a clash with the `False` that is defined in `Logic`. So in your environment you have two `False` your proposition and the one in `Logic` and they differ.

The statement you want to prove is equivalent to `forall A B : Prop, A \/ B -> A`

Comment: Oh, I see, so how can I state in Coq that by False in "A \/ False" I mean the False defined in Logic, not just some propositional variable named "False"?

Comment: `Goal forall A : Prop, A \/ False -> A.`